# jquery/ajax problem with page loaded and radio checked

Tags: jquery

I load a page with ajax/jquery, inside it i have some radio one of this may be checked, I'm trying to get value of checked radio, I can not get it on page loading but after it's loaded if a check another radio I can get value. here is example code:

html:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="radio" name="a" value="10"> a
<input type="radio" name="a" value="15"> b
<input type="radio" name="a" value="19"> c
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
var ch=$("input[name='a']:radio:checked");
    $.each(ch, function()
           {
               var chv=$(this).val();
               alert(chv);
           });

$(":radio[name='a']").click(function(){
    var ch=$("input[name='a']:radio:checked");
    $.each(ch, function()
           {
               var chv=$(this).val();
               alert(chv);
           });
});
});
```

Thanks in advance.
ciao
h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem your running in to is that you're not putting the code in a `document.ready()` wrapper. You could try doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // get value if clicked
 $("input:radio[name='a']").click(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   alert(value);
 });

 // get value on load
 var valueOnLoad = $("input[name='a']:radio:checked").val();
 alert(valueOnLoad);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Paul but when I load the page I receive in the alert undefined instead of the coorect value :( any idea? thanks again ciao h.

Comment: You'll need to add a 'checked="checked"' to one of your inputs otherwise it throws the undefined error in IE.  I.E.  <input type="radio" name="a" value="10" checked="checked">